# Is there a better way to get the Camera pixels than onPreviewFrame on Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

onPreviewFrame only gets called when the preview frames from the camera get displayed. I'm processing the image as an open gl texture using the same technique here:

http://nhenze.net/?p=172&cpage=1#comment-8424

But it seems like a waste to render the preview to the screen just so I can draw over it with my textured image. Is there a better way to get the pixels from the camera than during the call to onPreviewFrame?

Answer (score 4):

yes, you can use a SurfaceTexture. There's some mild trickiness here as it needs to be an external texture *not* the normal 2D texture.

This means that if you render the texture with ES2 you need some like

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
uniform samplerExternalOES s_texture;
```

in the fragment shader.

Example code:

```
    int[] textures = new int[1];
    // generate one texture pointer and bind it as an external texture.
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0]);
    // No mip-mapping with camera source.
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                            GL10.GL_LINEAR);        
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    // Clamp to edge is only option.
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


    int texture_id = textures[0];
    SurfaceTexture mTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texture_id);
    mTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

    Camera cam = Camera.open();
    cam.setPreviewTexture(mTexture);
```

Comment: For me, `setOnFrameAvailableListener()` aborts live preview. Reproduced on stock 4.1.2 Nexus S, so it's not some bug of an unlisted OEM. Instead, `setSurfaceTextureListener()` with `onSurfaceTextureUpdated()` callback may be used to track individual frames.